# Can't get WordPress to display all categories in Multisite

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using WordPress Multisite and I'm trying to display all the categories in every site on one page. When I'm on my admin account, the following code works. However, when I switch to any other account, no categories are shown.

```
$t=get_current_blog_id();
foreach(function_that_gets_blogs() as $k=>$blog){ 
    switch_to_blog($blog['blog_id']);
    print_r(get_categories(array('hide_empty'=>true))); // prints "array()"
    foreach(get_categories(array('hide_empty'=>true)) as $cat){
         ...
    }
}
switch_to_blog($t);
```

Why aren't the categories showing?

Comment: The `is_admin()` function does not check whether the current user has administrative rights or not - it is used to check whether the current page is part of the administration interface. Check for yourself in the documentation - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin .

Comment: I want the categories to show up for every user, not just the admin.

Comment: Your code works fine for me... Doubts: 1) Where are you using this code? 2) I know it's difficult on a MS, but can you turn off all non-essential plugins and check if it persists? 3) Any plugins inside [`mu-plugins`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like [b__](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1287812/b) said you should check for:

- Where are you using this code? (functions.php, plugin)
- You should disable plugins 1 by 1, to check if some are interfering
- and in the last case change theme

I've done something like you, and here is the code, in case you wanna try it:

```
// Current Site
$current = get_current_site();

// All Sites
$blogs = get_blog_list( 0, 'all' );

foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) {

    // switch to the blog
    switch_to_blog( $blog['blog_id'] );

    // get_categories args
    $args = array(
        'hide_empty' => true
    );

    $categories = get_categories( $args );

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

        $link = get_category_link( $category->term_id );
        $name = $category->name;

        printf( '<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a> ', $link, $name, $name );
    }

}

// return to the current site
switch_to_blog( $current->id );
```

### Update 2014/06/01

the function [`get_blog_list();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_blog_list) is deprecated since version 3.0, with that you should change that function within [`wp_get_sites();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_sites)

```
// Current Site
$current = get_current_site();

// All Sites
$blogs = wp_get_sites();

foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) {

    // switch to the blog
    switch_to_blog( $blog['blog_id'] );

    // get_categories args
    $args = array(
        'hide_empty' => true
    );

    $categories = get_categories( $args );

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

        $link = get_category_link( $category->term_id );
        $name = $category->name;

        printf( '<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a> ', $link, $name, $name );
    }

}

// return to the current site
switch_to_blog( $current->id );
```

Simple as that...

Comment: Hi @PratikJoshi I've just tested the code and it's working fine for me. Can I help you?

Comment: Sorry , I Had to fetch posts/categories from first blog in multisite.So as usual as a programmer , i thought Index of blog begins from 0 , But actually index of first blog was 1 , So I then changed it to 1 ,and it worked ,Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
<?php wp_list_categories("title_li=");?>
```